# How to generate a list of random floats within an interval with a minimum separation distance?

Tags: python, random

I want to generate a list of random floats within an interval while specifying a minimum distance/step size.

```
#Example of generations for the same min, max, minimum_step inputs:
min = 2.7
max = 24.3
minimum_step = 3.2
random_gen(min, max, minimum_step)

output:
a1 = [3.65, 6.8, 9.9]
a2 = [7.2, 10.9, 14.7, 19.0, 23.34]
a3 = [12.1]
a4=[2.7, 5.0, 8.2, 11.76, 15.8, 19.31, 24.3]
```

Comment: Does this mean the maximum step can be `maximum`? In that case prepare for the majority of the results to have 1 or 2 values exactly. `a4` also seems to be illegal because 2.7+3.2 = 5.9

Comment: @Reti43 has a valid point. I was not able to generate a single list with more than 3 values for your example in 200 million runs of a naive approach with `random.uniform(last+minimum_step, max)` sampling.

Comment: @Reti43, the 5 was a mistype it should be at least 5.9 as you said... Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the program to address comments of @Reti43.

```
import random as random
min = 2.7
max = 24.3
minimum_step = 3.2
# output list
a=[] 

# generate a first number with min as base and possible increment of 1. so the number can be max 4.7 
a.append(round(random.uniform(min, min+2),1)) 

for i in range(random.randint(1,10)): 
    # pick the last element in the list for next calculation
    min_start = a[len(a)-1] 
    
    # generate a new number with range of prev number and prev number + 1
    new_numb = random.uniform(min_start, min_start+1) 
    
    numb = round( new_numb+ random.uniform(minimum_step,new_numb+ minimum_step),2) # generate new random number and round it off 
    
    if numb < max: 
        a.append(numb)
print(a)
```

output generates list of random floats, like

```
[4.4, 12.95, 23.45]

[4.2, 11.63, 19.49]

[3.1, 9.24, 13.48, 23.41]

[4.4, 9.2, 22.44]
```

Comment: Thanks @Reti43, I think I have addressed your comments